# Create Websocket Dynamically on Button Click

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am creating a SPA for a client for which I would like to create a new Websocket after the user clicks the "login" button. The issue I am experiencing is that I can only get the Websocket to be created properly if it is done on the initial page load.

For example, the following code works properly creating the Websocket:

```
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
      <script>
        var pass;
        var socket = {};      
        socket = io('https://my.server.here', { query: "pass=mypasswordhere" });

        socket.on('error', function(err){
          console.log('Connection Failed: ' + err);
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function (data) {
            console.log('data: ' + data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
        });
</script>
```

However, when I attempt to create the Websocket as a result of a click event it is not created:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
      <script>
        var pass;
        var socket = {};
        function connect() {
          passInput = document.getElementById("password");
          pass = passInput.value;
          socket = io('https://my.server.here', { query: "pass=" + pass });

          socket.on('error', function(err){
            console.log('Connection Failed: ' + err);
          });

          socket.on('chat message', function (data) {
            console.log('data: ' + data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
          });
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="password" id="password">
            <button onclick="connect()">Connect</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are no errors showing in the console, nor does my server acknowledge the connection attempt when using the second code snippet.

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure `pass` is correct?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Yup, and if it weren't correct the 'error' event would be fired and notify as such.

Comment: What about looking at [connection event](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#event-connect) to see if it even try. (I assume you are using socket.io)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT My server watches for the SocketIO connection event. No connection event is fired on my server. I have also added a listener to the client code and it is never fired there either.

Comment: Dumb again but are you sure `connect()` get fired?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154151/discussion-between-nicktendo-and-gregory-neut).

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue? i am experiencing the same situation

Comment: @user3253067 I never did find a solution at the time, but I believe it was almost certainly related to the browser and/or my operating system. Possibly a security conflict. Have you tried an alternate browser?